# Add Sequential Number to returned data

Tags: php, function, loops, return

Newb here attempting something new (for me)

What I am attempting: I am attempting to create an idea number that iterates with each return, so the incident report for the giant kaiju (strange beast - aka Godzilla and friends) has an individual case number that is created programmatically). This means return one would be #1, return two would be #2, returned 3 would be #3 et al.

What I have done: I've attempted to put my int at the beginning, in the middle, at the end, after the return, etc, but regardless of where I put it, i always get the same number (12). I've read about iterating over at php.net, and looked through stack overflow and other places but i've not found something i could internalize/understand enough to replicate.

```
function __toString(){
$kID = 1;//kaiju incident number

    $myReturn = "<p> Incident ID: kID" . $kID ;
    $kID++; //not iterating thru
    $myReturn .= $kID ;

    $myReturn .= " | Massive Terrestial Organsim Reported: " . $this->movTitle . "   " ;
    $myReturn .= " | Location Name: " . $this->entWhat. " ";
    $myReturn .= " | Severity of Incident Reported: " . $this->movRating . "</p>" ;

    return $myReturn;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$kID` is set to `1` each time the function is called.  Make it `static` so it will retain it's values across function calls:

```
static $kID = 1;//kaiju incident number
```

Also:

```
$myReturn = "<p> Incident ID: kID" . $kID;
$kID++;
```

Comment: Wow - that totally worked - static is the coolest thing ever (i say that a lot, I seem to bump into kewl code things all they time. I'm a newb so i'm easily impressed i guess? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Right now every time your function is called, this code executes:

```
$kID = 1
$myReturn = $kID;
$kID++; 
$myReturn .= $kID ;
```

So `$kID` is being set to 1, then 2, hence the `12` in your output.

You need to define `$kID` outside your function. Maybe a rewrite like this:

```
function __toString(&$kID){
  $myReturn = "<p> Incident ID: kID" . $kID++ ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - it's very thorough and very much appreciated and helps me to see how returns work with a bit more clarity. Thanks